# Overlapping Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have data in a table like below.

```
    Col1 | Startdate | Enddate
    -----------------------
     A   |  D1       | D14
     B   |  D5       | D18
     C   |  D20      | D24
     D   |  D30      | D40
```

I want to get the col1 where the dates are overlapping and I am able to get it by referring to my table twice in my sql statement. However, the result set is like below.

```
    select t1.col1, t2.col1 from table t1, same_table t2
    where t1.col1!= t2.col1
      and t1.startdate <= t2.enddate
      and t1.enddate >= t2.startdate;

    Table1.Col1|Table2.col2
    -----------------------
       A       |   B
       B       |   A
```

Can anyone suggest how to filter out the 2nd record which is kind of a duplicate of first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `!=` to `<`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.col1 < t2.col1 
                 and t1.startdate <= t2.enddate      
                 and t1.enddate >= t2.startdate;
```

This will filter out record:

```
 Table1.col1 | Table2.col2
 -----------------------      
     B       |    A
```

**Note:** Use *explicit* ANSI compliant join syntax instead of old fashioned *implicit* syntax.

Comment: A and B are just 2 sample records I put. Actual data would be any string of 50 characters. In that I doubt if this will help. Can you confirm?

Comment: @user3123752 The logic remains the same. You can compare 50 characters wide strings just like any other string. The record having the *greatest* string value will be filtered out..

Comment: one last question, maybe dumb though, why is it recommended to use explicit join syntax? Is it just for readability purpose or anything else?

Comment: @Sandeep The explicit syntax is cleaner and easier to read. The old fashioned implicit syntax has been abandoned by the majority of the developers.